# Procedimiento almacenado oracle que devuelva registros

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy haciendo un procedimiento almacenado sobre la base de datos HR en pl/sql el cual me devuelva registros.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
PROCEDURE HR.Mostrar_Paises (continente NUMBER)
IS
  v_rut  VARCHAR(100);
BEGIN
  for c in(Select Country_Name into v_rut from HR.COUNTRIES where region_id=continente)
  loop v_rut:=c.Country_name;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_rut);
  end loop;
END;
```

Ejecuto el procedimiento almacenado:

```
BEGIN 
  HR.Mostrar_Paises(2);
COMMIT;
END;
```

Y no me muestra el resultado, solo me sale este mensaje:

> Procedimiento PL/SQL terminado correctamente.

Quisiera saber por qué motivo no me muestra el resultado.

Comment: ¿Cual programa cliente estás usando para ejecutar el script? ¿SQL*PLUS, Oracle SQL Developer, otro?

Comment: Hola estoy usando el Oracle SQL developer. Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que puedas ver los mensajes provenientes de las llamadas a `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`, debes ejecutar la sentencia siguiente antes de ejecutar el bloque PL/SQL:

```
set serveroutput on
```

O sea que puedes ejecutar el script de esta forma:

```
set serveroutput on

begin
  HR.Mostrar_Paises(2);
end;
```

Notarás que quité el `COMMIT;`, simplemente porque no veo que estés modificando datos, pero ese cambio no es pertinente a tu pregunta.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, gracias por el COMMIT no sabia que solo se ponia cuando se modificara los datos. Saludos